# SQL/ Function Loops

Tags: sql, function, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to write a function that will run until something is inserted into my table. I want it to check ever 10 seconds for an entry giving me an output message.

i know i will have to use the dbms_lock.sleep(10) and a while loop.

but any other advice would be very helpful.

Comment: Permanently polling the database sounds like complete overkill. Use an before/after insert trigger for this.

Comment: You can use DBMS Schedular. Once a function is scheduled to run for every 10 mins. If any output is RETURN by the function you can proceed with your process.

Comment: I agree with Frank. You can combine triggers with Oracle's notification system: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_cqn.htm#ADFNS018 or http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_publish.htm#ADFNS827

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to answer your question:

CAVEATS:

> I have assumed a basic knowledge of PL/SQL.
>
> I don't have an IDE in front of me today and I hve no knowledge of
>   your schema etc. so the code will be a best effort and you will need
>   to substitute your table sand columns etc. into it.
>
> I am assuming the using DBMS_OUTPUT will be enough to be enough for
>   your "output message"

**1) As you requested, loop and poll every 10 seconds**
This is a pretty nasty way of identifying when a record has been entered into your DB.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
FUNCTION check_for_record
AS
   -- Declare the cursor that checks for your record
   CURSOR db_rec_cur
   IS
      SELECT 1
        FROM <table_name>
       WHERE <criteria>;

   -- Variable to hold cursor output
   v_db_rec db_rec_cur%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   -- Enable DBMS_OUTPUT
   DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000000);

   -- Start the polling loop
   LOOP
      -- Output a message when testing for the record
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')||': Checking for DB record');

      --  Test if the record is in the DB
      OPEN db_rec_cur;
      FETCH db_rec_cur INTO v_db_rec;
      CLOSE db_rec_cur;

      -- Exit the polling loop when a record has been found
      EXIT WHEN v_db_rec IS NOT NULL;

      -- IF the loop has not exited, sleep foir 10 seconds
      DBMS_LOCK.sleep(10);

   -- End the loop
   END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN others
   THEN
      -- Check the cursor is closed
      IF db_rec_cur%ISOPEN
      THEN 
         CLOSE db_rec_cur;
      END IF;

      -- Output the error
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(SQLERRM);

      -- Propagate the error
      RAISE;
END check_for_record;
/
```

**2) Use a database trigger to notify you when a record has been inserted**

If you are looking for specific values that have been inserted then:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TRIGGER recordinsert_trg
AFTER INSERT ON <table_name>
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
   -- Enable DBMS_OUTPUT
   DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000000); 

   -- Check the ":new" values inserted to see if they match your criteria
   IF :new.<your_column> = <your_specific_value>
   THEN
      -- Output a message when testing for the record
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')||': Your value was inserted!');
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN others
   THEN
      -- Output the error
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(SQLERRM);

      -- Propagate the error
      RAISE;
END recordinsert_trg;
/
```

If you are just wanting to know when something/anything was inserted into your table then:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TRIGGER recordinsert_trg
AFTER INSERT ON <table_name>
DECLARE
BEGIN
   -- Enable DBMS_OUTPUT
   DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000000); 

   -- Output a message when the record was inserted
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')||': A record was inserted!');
EXCEPTION
   WHEN others
   THEN
      -- Output the error
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(SQLERRM);

      -- Propagate the error
      RAISE;
END recordinsert_trg;
/
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I'am totally agree with Frank Schmitt, the SGBD have the triggers thar are like events in a normal programming language, there are trigger for many operations over the (database, tables, rows, columns, etc) elements of the database.